# How to check in shell script if string variable contains a wildcard?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

I'm trying to check if string contains any wildcards.
Here is my failing attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
WILDCARDS='* . ? !  ] [' 
a="foo*bar"
for x in $REJECTED_WILDCARDS
do 
    if [[ "$a" == *"$x"* ]]
    then 
            echo "It's there!";
    fi 
done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is `.` included in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set wildcards into a bash array, like so

```
wildcards=( '*' '.' '?' '|' ']' '[' )
```

Then

```
a="foo*bar"
for wildcard in "${wildcards[@]}";
do
  if [[ $a == *"${wildcard}"* ]];
  then
    echo 'yes';
  fi;
 done
```

Comment: Great, this is what I've been looking for. Out of curiosity how do I add single quote to this list?

Comment: @user52028778, use double-quotes to quote it, like this: `wildcards=( '*' '.' '?' '|' ']' '[', "'" )`

Answer (score 5):

Slightly shorter and without a loop:

```
if [ "$a" != "${a//[\[\]|.? +*]/}"  ] ; then
  echo "wildcard found"
fi
```

The parameter substitution deletes all wildcards.
The strings are than no longer equal.

Comment: I like this approach better.